# PROMPT variable not changing prompt in Zsh?

Tags: zsh

The last line in my .zshrc is `export PROMPT="foo"`. I am using this because I heard this is the way to customize a ZSH prompt.

However, inside zsh my prompt does not show up as "foo".

Instead the PROMPT variable shows up as: `%K{blue}%n@%m%k %B%F{green}%24<...<%~ %}%F{white} %# %b%f%k` .

How can I debug this? I'm not sure what is overriding the environment variable, considering it is the last line in my .zshrc.

Comment: [Zsh/Bash startup files loading order (.bashrc, .zshrc etc.) | The Lumber Room](https://shreevatsa.wordpress.com/2008/03/30/zshbash-startup-files-loading-order-bashrc-zshrc-etc/)

Answer (score 2):

Turns out at the top of my .zshrc, I had:

```
autoload -Uz promptinit
promptinit
prompt adam1
```

which was overriding the prompt (I think).